# MySQL variable used in where statement if variable set

Tags: mysql

I would like to set a query up to filter by some user variables, if I choose to set them.

```
SET @item_number = 12345;

SELECT * FROM table 

    IF(@item_number IS NOT NULL, item_number = @item_number, NULL)
```

but based on my errors, I am not doing this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a proc? Or are you trying to build up some dynamic SQL.

If in a proc you can build up dynamic SQL and that might be easiest.

A method that is likely to be inefficient (due to trying to work out whether an index would help the query) but easy to understand would possibly be:-

```
SET @item_number = 12345;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE (@item_number IS NULL OR item_number = @item_number);
```

Comment: its just some dynamic SQL, so I can run a spot check on some values, or leave them out to run all values.

Comment: I would just build up the text for the SQL, omitting the check for item_number if @item_number is null. But whether this can safely be done will depend on the programming environment you are using.